# Filling In Missing Pieces

Tags: limits, derivatives

$$\cfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{1}{f(x)} = \displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} \left(\left(\frac{1}{f(x+h)}\right) - \frac{1}{f(x)}\right) = ... = -\frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2}$$

We know that the function f is differentiable on $[-\infty, \infty ]$ and $f(x) \ne 0$.

How do I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In first order in $h$, you get $\frac{1}{f(x+h)}\approx\frac{1}{f(x)+f^\prime(x)h}=\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{1}{1+h f^\prime(x)/f(x)}\approx\frac{1}{f(x)}(1-h\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)})$

If you now subtract $1/f(x)$ and divide by $h$, you get the result.